# Java Developed Zip File Not opening in Windows 7 default

Tags: java, windows-7, zip, zipoutputstream

I have created the Zip file using ZipOutputStream.  The zip file is created sucessfully and able to open using WinRar and Winzip file. And the files are showing inside the Zip File.

But same file, I am unable to open in Windows 7 default Zip Extractor.  While trying to extract using Windows 7 default extractor, there is no files inside the Zip File.  But actually there are multiple files available inside the Zip File.

Please help on this... Thx..

Comment: Do you have any file names in the zip file with non-ASCII characters?  Encoding of file names in ZIP files is [a tricky area](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/zip.html#encoding) and there's no single approach that will work everywhere.

Comment: Yes... I am trying to create the Zip file for 10 Pdfs and 5 JPG in java.

Comment: I mean the names of the files, not their contents - a binary file named `august.pdf` is OK, one named `août.pdf` may be problematic.

Comment: The long and sad story of unicode support in compressed folders http://blogs.msdn.com/b/michkap/archive/2012/01/04/10252916.aspx

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60745803/cannot-open-generated-zip-file
This link helped me fix my issue.

Answer (score 2):

My relative path was /somefolder/somefile.txt
when removing the first "/" everything started working perfectly.
(using the following path instead: "somefolder/somefile.txt").

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it worked for me

```
File zipedFile = new File(OUTPUT_ZIP_FILE);
 zipedFile.setWritable(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
outPutStream.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(file.getName()));
```